# How to use Groupby and Reindex in a Dask DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dask, dask-dataframe

I have a working pandas function, but don't know how to translate it to dask in a good way.

I have sales for certain products on specific dates, but I'm missing rows in my dataset when there were no sales:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "PRODUCT_ID": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3],
    "DATE": [
        pd.Timestamp(year=2019, month=1, day=2),
        pd.Timestamp(year=2019, month=1, day=4),
        pd.Timestamp(year=2019, month=1, day=8),
        pd.Timestamp(year=2019, month=1, day=3),
        pd.Timestamp(year=2019, month=1, day=7),
        pd.Timestamp(year=2019, month=1, day=5)
    ],
    "SALES": [5, 3, 2, 8, 1, 7],
}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

Begin DataFrame:

```
    PRODUCT_ID  DATE        SALES
0   1           2019-01-02  5
1   1           2019-01-04  3
2   1           2019-01-08  2
3   2           2019-01-03  8
4   2           2019-01-07  1
5   3           2019-01-05  7
```

My goal is to to fill in the sales for all PRODUCT_IDs for the date from 2019-01-01 until 2019-01-10. I found .groupby().reindex() to do the trick for me in pandas:

```
min_date = pd.Timestamp(year=2019, month=1, day=1)
max_date = pd.Timestamp(year=2019, month=1, day=10)
dates = pd.date_range(start=min_date, end=max_date, name="DATE")

df2 = (df.set_index('DATE')
            .groupby(['PRODUCT_ID'], as_index=True, sort=False)
                .apply(lambda df: df.reindex(dates, fill_value=0)
                                        .drop(columns=["PRODUCT_ID"]))
                    .reset_index(1, drop=False))
```

Which results in this filled dataframe with PRODUCT_ID as index:

```
           DATE            SALES
PRODUCT_ID                  
1          2019-01-01      0
1          2019-01-02      5
1          2019-01-03      0
1          2019-01-04      3
1          2019-01-05      0
1          2019-01-06      0
1          2019-01-07      0
1          2019-01-08      2
1          2019-01-09      0
1          2019-01-10      0
2          2019-01-01      0
2          2019-01-02      0
2          2019-01-03      8
2          2019-01-04      0
2          2019-01-05      0
2          2019-01-06      0
2          2019-01-07      1
2          2019-01-08      0
2          2019-01-09      0
2          2019-01-10      0
3          2019-01-01      0
3          2019-01-02      0
3          2019-01-03      0
3          2019-01-04      0
3          2019-01-05      7
3          2019-01-06      0
3          2019-01-07      0
3          2019-01-08      0
3          2019-01-09      0
3          2019-01-10      0
```

Now of course this is just a dummy dataset. In reality I have too much data to be using pandas, so I'm using Dask instead. However, I am not quite able to replicate above behavior in Dask. Are there any suggestions?

What I have so far:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

df = df.set_index("PRODUCT_ID")
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)

def custom_apply(df):
    df = df.reset_index()
    prd_id = df["PRODUCT_ID"].unique()[0]
    df = df.set_index("DATE")
    df = df.reindex(dates, fill_value=0)
    df["PRODUCT_ID"] = prd_id
    df = df.reset_index()
    df = df.set_index("PRODUCT_ID")
    print(df)
    return df

ddf_group = ddf.groupby(["PRODUCT_ID"]).apply(custom_apply, meta=pd.DataFrame).compute()
```

Through the print-statement in custom_apply I see that the dataframe created has the desired shape:

```
           DATE            SALES
PRODUCT_ID                  
1          2019-01-01      0
1          2019-01-02      5
1          2019-01-03      0
1          2019-01-04      3
1          2019-01-05      0
1          2019-01-06      0
1          2019-01-07      0
1          2019-01-08      2
1          2019-01-09      0
1          2019-01-10      0
```

However, I do get the following error and I'm a bit lost:

`AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'`

I also don't know if the apply function is actually scalable for a larger dataset. Any help is welcome.

Comment: Chaning the apply meta argument to `meta=ddf._meta` did solve my error.
Now the only question remains is: Is this approach scalable?

Comment: Thanks, I adjusted the date to also show that I want to have earlier dates filled in (which is not as easy with resample), forgot to adjust the output as well. Should be good now :)

Comment: And can you explain me where `dates_df` is defined?

Comment: That should have been `dates` as defined with the `pd.date_range()` function. I adjusted it. Thanks for pointing out the inconsistency!

Comment: Hi @Killian. This approach will work and be scalable providing every data of a given PRODUCT_ID fits in RAM. When you do the groupBy operation, you'll gather all the values with the same PRODUCT_ID into a single partition.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using resample. Most efficient solution would be to partition on product id and then map_partitions(lambda df: df.groupby('product_id').resample('D').asfreq())

In response to your comment: You should still definitely be using resample. If you want to extend the resample then insert a record at the beginning of the period you want the resample to begin at.

In that case you would use groupby apply and within your applied function, check the minimum date. If not equal to the start period you want, append a row with that date and then resample.

Comment: Resampling doesn't work, because it does work, because it only fills values between the min and max value of the existing dataframe. Not every product_id has a sale entry on every day, especially products that only came on offer later. So for these groups / partitions the resampling will miss the begin dates.